# How to run multiprocess on a windows server with pl/python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, postgresql, plpython

I am running a trigger function on INSERT/UPDATE that would create a new process that sends a post request to an api.

on a Ubuntu + PostgresQL 12 docker container running I was able to get the new process to form without an issue with the below code

```
pid=os.fork()
... do some logic
req = urllib2.Request(apiURI)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Now Attempting the same on my windows machine, its clear fork is not an option.

What is best practice when running multiprocessing on a windows system?

Comment: Use the `multiprocessing` module

Comment: @rdas I'm sure you mean the [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). Which is correct of course.

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` is not supported by [windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

You  can achieve the same using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
    print 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
```

Comment: Ok i see, so make sure that the attribute 'foo' is available before spawning new process.

how scalable is this type of solution? should i look into `from multiprocessing import Pool`?

Comment: If you need several processes that are a good option. 
I would also take a look at ProcessPoolExecuter if you are running python 3.2+  https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: interesting, so ProcessPoolExecuter wraps Pool with some helpful abilities. thanks will look more into this. 

is there any time we would choose pool over processPoolExecutor or does it not matter?

Comment: processPoolExecutor it's easier to use, I find e.g. it comes with a context manager.